# how to remove initital empty table Row

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to remove the empty row in my table. I have to set it to a empty object in my controller or I get a Error Message `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Note that I do not get this error in my plunkr when I comment out the empty object in the controller. not sure why i dont need it in the plunkr but I need it in my project.
[plunkr][1]`

```
  $scope.question = {
   options: [{}],
   option: { number: ''}
};

$scope.addOption = function() {
  $scope.question.options.push($scope.question.option);
     //clear out the option
       $scope.question.option = {number: '', description: ''}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
$scope.question = {
    options: [],
    option: {
      number: ''
    }
  };
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.question = {
    options: [],
    option: {
      number: ''
    }
  };

  $scope.addOption = function() {
    $scope.question.options.push($scope.question.option);
    //clear out the option
    $scope.question.option = {
      number: '',
      description: ''
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="question in question.options">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td>{{question}}</td>
      </tr>

      <table>
        <button ng-click="addOption()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show me how to apply it to this http://plnkr.co/edit/wtxQT4cJ1oFYkMHw0ji4?p=preview